# Unitialized Constant Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I have a rails 4 app where I have a controller like:

*app/controllers/api/v1/books_controller.rb*:

```
module Api::V1
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

and then my routes.rb:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :books
  end
end
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
uninitialized constant BooksController
```

Comment: module API::V1 assumes you are under API module... shouldn't that be module API; module V1; end; end ?
And in the project directory, you'll need the books controller file inside an directory called v1, which is inside a directory called api, inside the controllers folder of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class BooksController < ApplicationController
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

or this:

```
class Api::V1::BooksController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Both works for me.

Also there is a good practice to have some API Controller in like:

```
module Api
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
  end
end
```

in api folder. Or it can be in api version folder, with version namespace.